# Magento 2 - Creating admin page error 404

Tags: magento2, module, admin, custom

I have create an admin page but i get 404 error. What i'm wrong?

> etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="blog" frontName="blog">
            <module name="Altravista_Blog"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
      <add id="Altravista_Blog::blog" title="Blog" translate="title" module="Altravista_Blog" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="Altravista_Blog" resource="Altravista_Blog::blog"/>
      <add id="Altravista_Blog::blog_posts" title="Posts" translate="title" module="Altravista_Blog" parent="Altravista_Blog::blog" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="Altravista_Blog" action="blog/posts" resource="Altravista_Blog::blog"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> Controller/Adminhtml/Posts/Index.php

```
<?php
  namespace Altravista\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts;

  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/blog_posts_index.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         //return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        die('Hallo Admin');
    }
  }
?>
```

> this is the admin url /admin/blog/posts/index/key/

Comment: Can u share the admin url

Comment: i have update the question @NarayanS

Comment: Logged in as admin role or some other role? Check the _isAllowed permissions

Comment: i have admin role user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resource](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-admin-controller/)

[image]

Here is tested code

registration.php

```
<?php
    /**
    * Simple Hello World Module 
    *
    * @category    QaisarSatti
    * @package     QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
    * @author      Muhammad Qaisar Satti
    * @Email       qaisarssatti@gmail.com
    *
    */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Altravista_Blog',
    __DIR__
);
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/**
    * Simple Hello World Module 
    *
    * @category    QaisarSatti
    * @package     QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
    * @author      Muhammad Qaisar Satti
    * @Email       qaisarssatti@gmail.com
    *
    */ -->
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Altravista_Blog" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
      <add id="Altravista_Blog::blog" title="Blog" translate="title" module="Altravista_Blog" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="Altravista_Blog" resource="Altravista_Blog::blog"/>
      <add id="Altravista_Blog::blog_posts" title="Posts" translate="title" module="Altravista_Blog" parent="Altravista_Blog::blog" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="Altravista_Blog" action="blog/posts" resource="Altravista_Blog::blog"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="blog" frontName="blog">
            <module name="Altravista_Blog"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
  namespace Altravista\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts;

  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/blog_posts_index.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         //return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        die('Hallo Admin');
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: thanks but it does not works :(

Comment: @Altravista i tested your code it is working fine.

Comment: I have delete all other module files, copy your code but does not works for me maybe some comand line to launch?

Comment: Php bin/magento setup:upgrade to run the module

Comment: just do it also flush cache and compile and reindex

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.3

Comment: I have create all files and folder again, copy same code and now it works. I cannot understand why but it works. thanks for all